# How do I inherit from a generic base class?

Tags: vb.net

Lets say I have this class

```
Public Class Base(Of T)
    Public SomeField as T
End Class
```

and now I want to inherit it in another class that would also be template but a little different

```
Public Class LittleDifferent : Inherits Base
    Public SomeOtherField as T
End Class
```

So now if I wanted, I could make an object like this

```
Dim derp as New LittleDifferent(of Integer)
```

Obviously the code provided is broken since I don't know the correct syntax. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make the subclass generic as well:

```
Public Class LittleDifferent(Of T)
    Inherits Base(Of T)

    Public SomeOtherField as T
End Class
```

PS: Please try to avoid [public fields](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/161303/33843).